# How to insert in a specific column of a table?

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I want to insert something in a specific column of a table:-

```
$this->db->insert('images.image',$data); // this query don't work
```

my table name in `images` and my column name is `image`. I want to insert $data in it.

I am using codeigniter.

Comment: And what THE LOG say to you?
first parameter should be table name - images
second parameter hash array where key is column name and value is just a value - `array('image' => $data,);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your controller code

```
$data=array('image'=>your_value);

$result = $this->your_model->insert($data);
```

and your model code

```
function insert($data){
 $result = $this->db->insert('images',$data);
 }
```

Comment: @stay then what else ;)

Comment: Oh yes.. I forgot. Now its ok?

Answer (score 2):

When inserting data best use data array like so.

**Disclaimer:** This is just example code help you along.

Model Function Example

```
public function add($data) {
  $data = array(
    'CustomerName' => $data['CustomerName'],
    'ContactName' => $data['ContactName'],
    'Address' => $data['Address'],
    'City' => $data['City'],
    'PostalCode' => $data['PostalCode'],
    'Country' => $data['Country']
  );

  $this->db->insert('tablename', $data);
}
```

Controller Function Example

```
<?php

public function index() {
   $this->load->model('modal_name');

  // Your post data can go here also.
  // Example Only:

  $CustomerName = $this->input->post('CustomerName');

  if (isset($name)) {
    $data['CustomerName'] = $CustomerName;
  } else {
    $data['CustomerName'] = '';
  }

  // On view would be <input type="text" name="CustomerName" />

  $ContactName = $this->input->post('ContactName');

  if (isset($ContactName)) {
    $data['ContactName'] = $ContactName;
  } else {
    $data['ContactName'] = '';
  }

  // On view would be <input type="text" name="ContactName" />

  $Address = $this->input->post('Address');

  if (isset($Address)) {
    $data['Address'] = $Address;
  } else {
    $data['Address'] = '';
  }

  // On view would be <input type="text" name="Address" />

  $City = $this->input->post('City');

  if (isset($City)) {
    $data['City'] = $City;
  } else {
    $data['City'] = '';
  }

  // On view would be <input type="text" name="City" />

  $PostalCode = $this->input->post('PostalCode');

  if (isset($PostalCode)) {
    $data['PostalCode'] = $PostalCode;
  } else {
    $data['PostalCode'] = '';
  }

  // On view would be <input type="text" name="PostalCode" />

  $Country = $this->input->post('Country');

  if (isset($Country)) {
    $data['Country'] = $Country;
  } else {
    $data['Country'] = '';
  }

  // On view would be <input type="text" name="Country" />

  $this->load->library('form_validation');

  $this->form_validation->set_rules('CustomerName', 'Customer Name', 'required');

  if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE ) {
    $this->load->view('page', $data);
  } else {
    $this->model_name->add($this->input->post()); 
    // You can use $this->input->post() this will let you get all post with in this function

    /*
      var_dump($this->input->post());
      exit;
    */
    redirect('success_page');
  }
}
```

Comment: parameter $data is coming from controller and it has record which i want to insert in a column (image) in table images.

Comment: This here if you have input post like so `$this->model_name->add($this->input->post());`  then you can use data in model Just have a play round with test

Comment: How can I write this INSERT INTO images (image)
VALUES ($data); in codeigniter syntax

Comment: I have update my answer on how to insert values but for images you would need to integrate the **file upload library  do upload** function in with that code. What I have done should help you along but should read user guide and Google search more.